# Do I have to place my Python project inside the conda environment directory?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am learning Python and downloaded it with Anaconda in Ubuntu (learning Linux too). When I create a conda environment, it generates a directory with the name of the env like this: `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv1`

When I activate the environment and launch my editor (VScode) I then select the interpreter from the active environment. When I save my .py file, do I have to save it inside the environment directory? That folder contains other folders and packages that are put there by conda. If I need a package from that environment and my project folder is not in the myenv1 directory, will it not work?

Comment: it will work . you can keep it outside env . all you have to do is associate the environment path in VScode settings of that project. env are create just to make changes in python  environment of that project without effecting overall python envriment(conda one) which is being used by other project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until and unless you are inside the environment i.e. environment is activated, you'll have access to all packages installed in the conda environment. Run the python file inside the environment. There is no requirement of placing your project inside the environment.

Go to your project directory then open terminal or open terminal in VSCode then put this command

```
conda activate myenv1
```

If the environment is activated, it will be shown in left part of your bash prompt like

```
(myenv1) username: /path/to/project $
```

Then,

```
python my_script.py
```

Comment: So, I can create a project and structure it properly in another directory but I have to always remember to activate the environment for the particular project. I will only have access to the packages installed in that particular environment either from conda or whatever else I manually install.

This is fun and gives me headaches at the same time. Thank you for clarifying and alleviating the headaches!

Comment: @AndresRolonViera Good that you understood. Environments come in handy when you work in multiple projects and you wanna segregate the packages.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to save any file in the virtual environment folder. Once the environment is activated, it acts like an independent environment. But remember you will have to install all the packages again which are not available in Conda.